# Fatal Error Using Amazon SubmitFeedSample

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use the Amazon API to update our product quantities on Amazon but when trying yo test the API I keep getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MarketplaceWebService_Client' not found in......
```

I don't know what the issue is. I downloaded the code from Amazon and put it on my server, put in my credentials in the ".config.inc.php" file and I get this error. Not quite sure what to do.

This is the code that is causing the error

```
 $service = new MarketplaceWebService_Client(
 AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
 AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
 $config,
 APPLICATION_NAME,
 APPLICATION_VERSION);
```

Thanks

Comment: What file? The PHP file has an include statement and it's the file that includes my credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path Client.php in your downloaded code is correctly included. `MarketplaceWebService_Client` is a class inside the Client.php file.

Comment: Just use 'include_once('Client.php');'? I did that and it did nothing.

Comment: If you're making multiple calls, sure that should work.

Comment: It didn't I didn't modify anything besides adding my credentials.